# Show the GUI every time the Notepad window is opened

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to create the code, that will show the `foo` window every time the Notepad is opened. The problem is, that if I close `foo` once, it will not be shown again (when I open Notepad next time). Currently I am using the following code:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinWaitActive, Notepad
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest1 , button 1
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest2 , button 2
Gui, Show,, foo
Return

Test1:
Run test1.ahk
Return

Test2:
Run test2.ahk
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Persistent

Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest1 , button 1
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest2 , button 2

SetTimer, Show_Gui, 300
return

Show_Gui:
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class Notepad
{
    Gui, cancel
    return
}
; Otherwise:
SetTimer, Show_Gui, off
Gui, Show,, foo
WinWaitClose, ahk_class Notepad
SetTimer, Show_Gui, on
Return

Test1:
; do sth
return

Test2:
; do sth
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Examples